# How to use Drupal View

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

i am using Drupal 6.x

I had created two users i.e. a user with all permission i.e. Webmaster and other is member. The permissions of member are restricted and are allowed only to create story, delete own story and edit own story. However when i logged in with member name i got only three option i.e.:

1. My account
2. Create Content
3. Log Out

The post submitted by that user is not visible. I want to display all post published by that user in its account detail, and here he/she can easily edit, delete or modify his/her content. How it can be possible. Have you any idea. If yes then please guide me step by step. waiting for your reply. Thanks in advance for this support.

Comment: consider posting your question directly on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of permission issue, steps to solve this issue

1. Create a view to list the story with edit button.
2. Go to the admin/user/permissions and give create, edit and view permission for the user.
3. publish the created article via admin user.
4. Last assign the created view block to users home page.